# Enabling minor modes via customize

Tags: customize, minor-mode

I see that minor modes defined via [`define-minor-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html) have a variable that has the same name as the function and the following documentation:

> Setting this variable directly does not take effect; either customize
>   it (see the info node ‘Easy Customization’) or call the function
>   ‘editorconfig-mode’.

However, customizing doesn't seem to work for me.  The value of the variable ends up as `nill`, “CHANGED outside Customize”, and the minor mode is not enabled unless I additionally add the following to my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(editorconfig-mode 1)
```

In this example I'm using [`editorconfig-mode`](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-emacs), but I have the issue with other modes too.

What am I missing?  Do I need to do something extra or in a different order to get these customized variable to take effect?

Comment: I think that changing the variable value using Customize does not work (do the right thing) for some minor modes. Does the doc for `editorconfig-mode` say anything about this? If not, and if you don't get a helpful answer here, consider letting the mode author know - its doc should make this clear, if it's intended.

Comment: FYI this facility is working for me for the example `editorconfig-mode` in Emacs 26.3.  I suggest you try to reproduce the issue with a minimal config; something in your normal config may be interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(package-initialize)` must appear before `(custom-set-variables …)` in the initialisation file.

The next major release of GNU Emacs, version 27, will initialise packages before loading the init file, so this will no-longer be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of global minor modes.

`define-minor-mode` declares a *default* custom<sup>1</sup> `:set` value for the mode variable like so:

```el
(unless set (setq set '(:set #'custom-set-minor-mode)))
```

That function is:

```el
(defun custom-set-minor-mode (variable value)
  ":set function for minor mode variables.
Normally, this sets the default value of VARIABLE to nil if VALUE
is nil and to t otherwise,
but if `custom-local-buffer' is non-nil,
this sets the local binding in that buffer instead."
  (if custom-local-buffer
      (with-current-buffer custom-local-buffer
        (funcall variable (if value 1 0)))
    (funcall variable (if value 1 0))))
```

So this facility ought to be working generally, unless the mode in question has clobbered that default without replicating the behaviour.

---

<sup>1</sup> The variable is only defined with `defcustom` if the mode is global, so this has no effect for buffer-local minor modes.